# Visual Studio 2015 Blank App (Universal Windows): CS0731

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a project "Universal Windows". For this I have the Visual Studio 2015 Blank app (Universal Windows) used template.

I now get the following compilation error:

> CS0731  The type forwarder for type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1' in assembly 'Windows' causes a
>   cycle

In the following source:

```
string filename = "SampelData.json";
var path = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =  await path.GetFileAsync(filename);                   
string jsonResult = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

be precise, the fault displayed for `await path.GetFileAsync(filename)` and `await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file).`

The analysis of the error message Microsoft has not helped me:
[CS0731](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228508.aspx)

---

**Update**

As to X of the error caused by faulty under load metadata. The type forwarder for type 'type' in assembly 'assembly' causes a cycle

> This error can only occur with improperly formed imported metadata. It
>   cannot occur with only C# source.

Do I have reset the settings of the VS2015, by deleting the chache folder content and run `devenv /resetuserdata`.

Unfortunately, without success

***Update 2***

Still no solution, the file treatment corresponds to the Microsoft documentation, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185401.aspx.

I here actually wanted to load sample data. But I have currently developed also the WebService for the provision of data. I let my sample data just about this WebService deploy. This is but I think no satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble had dissolved with the update 2 of Visual Studio 2015. At least the problem no longer consists, since installation of the update.

Comment: It still consists in VS 2017 and Portable DLL project